# Can we have an edit text as a menu item in android 3.0 honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

Can we have an edit text box inside our menu which gets displayed in the action bar
and if we can then how can we get click events on this edit text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a search bar to the action bar but not as a menu item... what do you even meen with "as a menu item"?

Comment: I mean when we add anything to our action bar we put those items in the menu.xml & then inflate the menu using onCreateOptionsMenu() & then get click events on them using onOptionsItemSelected() So can I have an edit text as a menu item. There is a tag called android:actionLayout available for android 3.0 . Here we can have any layout which will be displayed in the action bar. I am able to do that but I want to know that how do I get listeners on these objetcs (eg. Edit text, Button) which are defined in the layout

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. It is done like this (only for android 3.0 honeycomb)
Placing an edit text in action bar
for placing the items
use this TAG in your item in the menu xml

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/search_bar"
```

define edit text & button in the search_bar layout.

Now for getting listeners on them do it like this -
in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
et = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.search_bar).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.searchbar);        
findBtn = (ImageButton)menu.findItem(R.id.search_bar).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.find);
```

and then place listeners for these items. It will work fine

Comment: I've been trying to make a "navigation" bar like this for 2 days... worked perfectly, THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it but are you able to use actionlayout from code? in that way you could use get the Text box this way:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.random_layout, null); 
EditText editText = (EditText )wrapper.findViewById(R.id.edit); 

// 
//code to set the listener 
// 

// 
//set the android:actionLayout to wrapper etc. 
//
```

Im at work so I can't make some research so this is just speculations...